# How do you add a custom view on a view in Android?

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a graph view (custom view) in Android and a main view. Depending on the user's preference I want to add 1-5 graph views onto my main view but am not quite sure how to. (I'm using purely Java and not xml). I was reading that I might have to use a Relative Layout or something in order to stack views.

Any advice or suggestions are welcome

Comment: Does this mean your view should be scrollable when having 5 graphs for example? By the way, this is possible with drawing on Canvas.

Comment: @Lumis No, I'm wanting to draw the graph on top of the previous graph. For instance, lets say my first graph is a circle, my next graph of a tangent function. I would want to display the tangent graph over the circle graph. (I don't want to just draw them on top because of information I want to get from each graph view). Hope that clears it up a bit :)

Comment: In a custom view you can draw an infinite number of graphs over each other, with or without their transparency. How will the program know or be informed by the user when to draw the next graph?

Comment: @Lumis I have a method in my main layout that reads data from a file and that determines whether to draw another graph or remove previous graphs. Alternatively I could expand it to allowing the user to specify the values, but for right now I have all the data in a file and assumed.

Comment: In that case all you need is a custom view which has a public method. You pass the data to that method and it will draw the graph.

Comment: @Lumis Thank you for your help, I'll give it a try and if I run into issues I'll post another question. (Gave you an upvote on a question for your help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your activity you probably have something like this towards the begining of your onCreate() method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

inside your main.xml file you probably have an element that is some kind of layout. I will assume LinearLayout for now, but it works similarly with all types. You'll need to get a reference to this layout and to do that it must have an id. So if that layout does not have something like this in it you need to add it:

```
android:id="@+id/myMainLayout"
```

Then back in your java sometime after you've called setContentView() you can find the reference to your layout with something like this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myMainLayout);
```

Once you have a reference to your layout you can add your graph views to it with something like this:

```
myLayout.addView(graph1);
myLayout.addView(graph2);
//etc...
```

If you want to skip the xml layout all together you are allowed to make your layout in java. To do that it would like this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(YourActivity.this);
myLayout.addView(graph1);
myLayout.addView(graph2);
setContentView(myLayout);
```

Note that you can only call setContentView() once so you'll need to pass some kind of Layout to it if you want to add more than 1 View.

Edit:

I have never specifically tried but I would think you could call addView() from the constructor in your custom view:

```
public CustomView() {
    this.addView(anotherView);
}
```

do you have a custom view for your layout too?

Comment: If I read your post correctly, you are setting the Layout and adding the Views in the Activity. Is there a way to do this inside the View rather than the Activity?

Comment: Currently I have two Java classes that extend View. I haven't set a layout to either of them. On another note, I don't seem to have the `addView()` method for my view. The reason I'm asking if it is possible to do it in the view is because I have a method in there that grabs data and draws new graphs based on the data and either adds or removes previous graphs

Comment: addView() is a method of ViewGroup, you'd have to extend that to use it.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I see it also has a removeView method. Will extending a ViewGroup rather than View affect what I already have? (Also I apologize if my terminology has been off in previous responses were confusing regarding layouts and views). I'll give the `addView` a try.

Comment: I am not sure, if you post the code for both of your custom Views I could give you a better idea if it would affect anything. And no problem at all its confusing how somethings seems to have different names in different places.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I'll give it a go and if I run into issues I'll post a new question with some code. For now, my initial question has been answered

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a custom view as graph. One needs to have a LinearLayout somewhere in the layout which has ID set to @+id/ll and size of the graph:

```
public class RootActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    int[] graphData = {3,5,2,7,4,8,1,5,9};

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);  
    GraphView graphView = new GraphView(this);
    ll.addView(graphView);


    //call this method with every new set of data
    graphView.drawGraph(graphData);


}


class GraphView extends View{
 int[] graphData;
 Paint graphPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 int screenH;
 int screenW;
 int colW;
 int colH;
 int columnCount;

 public GraphView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    graphPaint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    graphPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
}


 @Override     
 public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {         
     super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);         
     screenW = w;         
     screenH = h; 
 }


public void drawGraph(int[] graphData){
    this.graphData = graphData;
    columnCount = graphData.length;
    invalidate();
}


@Override     
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {         
    super.onDraw(canvas); 

    colW = (screenW - 10) / columnCount;
    int graphStep = 20;
    int columnSpace = 5;

    canvas.drawText("GRAPH", 10, 10,  graphPaint);

    for (int i= 0 ; i < columnCount; i++){
        //draw columns from bottom up
        canvas.drawRect(
                new Rect(
                i * colW + 5, 
                screenH - 5 - (graphData[i] * graphStep), 
                i * colW + 5 + colW - columnSpace, 
                screenH - 5     
                ), 
                graphPaint);
    }



}
```

Comment: I went ahead and posted another question on a similar topic, if you are interested in view it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326535/what-should-my-android-layout-look-like

Comment: If I'm not mistaken would this be using only one view but drawing multiple graphs on that one view?

Comment: Yes, just one view as it should be.

Comment: Interesting, I like this idea. I'll have to see if I can still keep track of which lines are which while using this way. This would keep it much simpler than having to make the views draw on top of the previous views.

Comment: Alternatively, what would be your suggestion if the `drawGraph()` method was private?